# Add a unique identifier to the same column value in R data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation, uniqueidentifier

I have a data frame as follows:

```
     index val  sample_id
1     1    14      5
2     2    22      6
3     3    1       6
4     4    25      7
5     5    3       7
6     6    34      7
```

For each row with the sample_id, I would like to add a unique identifier as follows:

```
index val  sample_id
1     1    14      5
2     2    22      6-A
3     3    1       6-B
4     4    25      7-A
5     5    3       7-B
6     6    34      7-C
```

Any suggestion? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::group_by(df, sample_id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(sample_id = paste(sample_id, LETTERS[seq_along(sample_id)], sep = "-"))

 index   val sample_id
  <int> <dbl> <chr>    
1     1    14 5-A      
2     2    22 6-A      
3     3     1 6-B      
4     4    25 7-A      
5     5     3 7-B      
6     6    34 7-C
```

Comment: Neat. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### Base R

```r
dat$id2 <- ave(dat$sample_id, dat$sample_id,
               FUN = function(z) if (length(z) > 1) paste(z, LETTERS[seq_along(z)], sep = "-") else as.character(z))
dat
#   index val sample_id id2
# 1     1  14         5   5
# 2     2  22         6 6-A
# 3     3   1         6 6-B
# 4     4  25         7 7-A
# 5     5   3         7 7-B
# 6     6  34         7 7-C
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(sample_id) %>%
  mutate(id2 = if (n() > 1) paste(sample_id, LETTERS[row_number()], sep = "-") else as.character(sample_id)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

Minor note: it might be tempting to drop the `as.character(z)` from either or both of the code blocks. In the first, nothing will change (here): base R allows you to be a little sloppy; if we rely on that and *need* the new field to always be `character`, then in that *one rare circumstance* where all rows have unique `sample_id`, then the column will remain `integer`. `dplyr` is much more careful in guarding against this; if you run the tidyverse code without `as.character`, you'll see the error.

Comment: @markus iteration and refinement, thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create unique tags for the same `sample_id`, maybe you can try `make.unique` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  sample_id = ave(as.character(sample_id),sample_id,FUN = function(x) make.unique(x,sep = "_"))
)
```

which gives

```
  index val sample_id
1     1  14         5
2     2  22         6
3     3   1       6_1
4     4  25         7
5     5   3       7_1
6     6  34       7_2
```

Comment: Very useful solution. In my case, I have to use -A and -B to distinguish those replicates. Thank you.