# How to append incremental values for duplicated column values and then assign as rownames?

Tags: r

`Column A` contains duplicated values.
I want to assign incremental values to the duplicated values in `Column A` and separate it with a `.` delimiter.
Then, assign Column A as rownames.

Input:

|  | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12 |
| 2 | B | 34 |
| 3 | B | 56 |
| 4 | D | 78 |
| 5 | E | 90 |
| 6 | E | 120 |
| 7 | E | 456 |

Expected output:

|  | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B.1 | 34 |
| B.2 | 56 |
| D | 78 |
| E.1 | 90 |
| E.2 | 120 |
| E.3 | 456 |

Comment: Related: [Disambiguate non-unique elements in a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062748/disambiguate-non-unique-elements-in-a-character-vector); [Add a unique identifier to the same column value in R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000543/add-a-unique-identifier-to-the-same-column-value-in-r-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `by` approach with `seq_along` and `paste0`.

```
s <- 'Column_A'  ## column to sanitize

by(dat, dat[[s]], \(x) {
  u <- paste0('.', seq_along(x[[s]]))
  u <- replace(u, length(u) == 1L, '')
  x[[s]] <- paste0(x[[s]], u)
  x
  }) |> unsplit(dat[[s]])
#   Column_A Column_B
# 1        A       12
# 2      B.1       34
# 3      B.2       56
# 4        D       78
# 5      E.1       90
# 6      E.2      120
# 7      E.3      456
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Column_A = c("A", "B", "B", "D", "E", "E", "E"
), Column_B = c(12L, 34L, 56L, 78L, 90L, 120L, 456L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: Or `ave(dat$Column_A, dat$Column_A, FUN = \(x) if(length(x) > 1) paste(x, seq_along(x), sep = ".") else x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame('col.A' = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E'), 
                 'col.B' = c(12, 34, 56, 78, 90, 120, 456))

# Check for duplicates in column A
duplicates <- duplicated(df$`col.A`) | duplicated(df$`col.A`, fromLast = TRUE)

# Create a vector to store the new values
new_values <- list()

# Loop through the duplicates and assign new values
for (i in which(duplicates)) {
  if (df[i, 'col.A'] %in% names(new_values)) {
    new_values[[df[i, 'col.A']]] <- new_values[[df[i, 'col.A']]] + 1
    df[i, 'col.A'] <- paste0(df[i, 'col.A'], '.', new_values[[df[i, 'col.A']]])
  } else {
    new_values[[df[i, 'col.A']]] <- 1
    df[i, 'col.A'] <- paste0(df[i, 'col.A'], '.1')
  }
}

df <- df %>%
  column_to_rownames('col.A')
```